# Pentaho Kettle - "Text File Output" order of write?

Tags: pentaho, kettle, pentaho-spoon, pdi

If multiple files are to be written to? Does Pentaho's "Text file Output" guarantee the records to be written in the order of what is sent to it? Or while dealing with multiple files and multiple streams, it has some internal logic which might change the order of record writes?

Comment: Can you add the samples for different inputs?

Comment: The inputs are nothing but XML snippets. Typical XML only.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I have used it, it writes lines in the same order it gets.

Of course if you have the same file in multiple steps, Pentaho won't assure you which of them will be executed first as all steps are processed in parallel.

If that's the case, and you need to write one stream before the other, use a blocking step, but keep in mind that your job will execute slower.